# Image in article

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, phrase-requests

What would you call an image in a newspaper article that appears in the flow of the article with text wrapped around it?
For example an article with two columns — on the right column there's an image with wrapping around it.
What would you call it?
In-line image? Article in-line image? Paragraph image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Illustration* is the only word that fits in normal English.  If you want more technical editing terms, you could try *box*, *figure* or *image*.  There is, so far as I know, no one word for an image inserted into an article rather than next to it.

Comment: It may just be in the US, but I don't think we would use `illustration` very often for an image in a newspaper article, unless perhaps the image was drawn rather than a photograph.  Certainly the definition of `illustration` covers photographs, but it just has a connotation of something that's drawn by hand, probably because the most likely place we'd encounter that word would be in reference to children's books and diagrams and whatnot rather than exemplary photographs.  We'd probably use `picture` or `photograph` for a print newspaper, and `picture` or `image` for an online newspaper.

Comment: @Phoenix: interesting.  What would you use for a graph  demonstrating the point made? (I was going to say *illustrating* but that's begging the question.)  *Illustration* is BrEng for all three cases, I would say.

Comment: @TimLymington: A graph?  Probably just `graph`, perhaps `chart`, depends on how the data is modeled.  If it were a picture of something like, say, an engine with the parts labeled or a cutaway or whatever, then it would be a `diagram`.  I can honestly say that I've never in my life heard anyone say something like "Take a look at this illustration in this article on page 2," it's always "Take a look at this picture (or photograph)..." or "Did you see that graph in the Times today?"

Comment: @Phoenix: I believe you're correct, except when you discuss all the ... images ... in a publication as a group. Then we may say "the illustrations". But then I fall back to agreeing that if they are all or mostly photographs, we would say "the pictures" or "the photos".

Comment: I was thinking of using it where a prescribed layout is required for an editor of an article. There needs to be an image/graphic/etc in one paragraph on a particular column. I think to describe this, the wording 'an illustration' covers it.

Comment: @Jay: The more I think about it, I've only really heard `illustration` used with books with drawn pictures, and even then usually in the general sense of all the pictures in a book, e.g. "This book has wonderful illustrations, especially the picture on page 23."  Except textbooks, as they have `figures`.  There's still the general knowledge of both the noun and verb form definitions, but it just doesn't get used much as "a picture example" or "to give an explanation" when `example` and `explain` are available.

Answer (score 2):

In computer graphic layout, we talk about "in-line images", but I don't think this is a term used and understood by the average person. I don't know if printers have different terminology.

Comment: Precisely- But then I wanted this for an average person.

Answer (score 0):

*Graphic* (without an 's' at the end).  Can be an all encompassing term for non-textual content in any context, appearing in/ on any of the media.

I do not have authentic references at hand right now. However, I am sure this term is emerging as a well understood and accepted catch-all, esp., in journalism.

Comment: Would an audio clip be considered graphic? Seems the word *visual* should be a qualifier.

Comment: A graphic is usually either computer-generated or made through the graphic arts (etchings, woodcuts, lithograph, &c.) @jimm101 I think this is the noun graphic.