# What is the difference between "image", "picture", "photograph" and "illustration"

Tags: meaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between “photo” and “image”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23690/what-is-the-difference-between-photo-and-image)
>   [Difference between “picture” and “photo”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7028/difference-between-picture-and-photo)

For my magister dissertation I need to rely on an accurate definition of what an *image*, a *picture*, a *photograph* and an *illustration* refer to.

Therefore, I would like you to help me figure out the differences.

Comment: Why can't you use dictionary definitions?

Comment: Of course, there is also *[figure](http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/chambers/features/chref/chref.py/main?query=figure&title=21st&sourceid=Mozilla-search)* [sense 9]

Comment: Also related: [Image in article](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51397/image-in-article) and [What exactly is a “figure” in a scientific paper?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54805/what-exactly-is-a-figure-in-a-scientific-paper)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Matt that you would want to use a good dictionary to look up your terms, but I can tell you how we use these terms at a publishing company. A *photograph* is an image taken with a camera. An *illustration* is a drawing of some sort, generated by an artist (that includes digital art). (If I said to any of our editors "Is the cover art an illustration?" they know I don't mean a photo.) The term *image* is used for any photo or artwork, but usually means the artwork is in a computer file, ready to be placed in a design document. The term *picture* is synonymous with *photo*. And as @Andrew Leach mentioned in his comment, we use the word *figure* in our clinical journal to refer to the images that are cited in the text.

If you are asking how you should refer to photos, diagrams, and illustrations in your dissertation, I think *figure* is the word to use. It covers them all.

Answer (score 0):

A *photograph* is a picture that is made by a camera. You can shorten the word to *photo* which is less formal. A *picture* is another word for referring to a photograph, especially in newspaper, magazines, ... In those cases you can also say *illustration* or *figure*, especially when referring to a diagram.

> This illustration shows the process in form of a diagram.
>
> In figure one, you can see that the value changed over the years.

A *image* is a picture that you can see in a mirror, on a TV, ... Again, you can use *picture* in that context.

A *picture* can also refer to a painting or drawing.

Moreover, both image and picture can mean an impression or mental image that you have of someone.